# Styling/ Theming Google Maps using API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to style Google Maps for my website like here: http://www.sidewalkprophets.com/shows
They only show the USA and unfortunately the site uses API V2.

Is the same possible using Google Maps API V3? Can someone help me?

Comment: Here is the Google Maps documentation for stylizing maps: [Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#StyledMaps) and [Dynamic Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple form to you do this without so much scripting, etc.

You can use the gmap3.net tool, its simples to edit your map how do you like to.

Check this links:

[Gmap3 editor tool](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)

[Tutorial](http://gmap3.net/api/set-styled-map.html)

To lock the position you can use `map.Options{ draggable: false};` so the user can't drag the map and them you set the latitude and longitude that you want and the zoom level. This is a simple example:

```
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mappy');

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 12, //select the zoom that you want
draggable: false, //this will lock the draggable option
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.563594, -46.654239), //change here the latitude and longitude 
mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
pode ser ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, TERRAIN
map = new google.maps.Map( mapDiv, mapOptions ); //this will include the variables in one to create the map with the options
```

Good lucky =) !

Comment: I edited the code, check it, if your problem was solved, please check the answer to another users that have the same problem =)